# Android - Program crashes when there is not input in editText fields

Tags: android

So i'm having a problem in my code which is probably simple to solve but its my first app so cut me some slack. When I enter no values in my editText box my app crashes. Im semi aware why it occurs but I cant seem to solve it.

`public void onButtonClick( View v)
    {
        Double n1  , n2 , answer1;
        EditText e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num1);
        EditText e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num2);
        TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer);
        n1 = Double.parseDouble(e1.getText().toString());
        n2 = Double.parseDouble(e2.getText().toString());
        if (n1.toString().length()< 0 || n2.toString().length()< 0){
            t1.setText("Please enter a number into both the base and height");
        }else {
            answer1 = ((n1 * n2) / 2);
            t1.setText(Double.toString(answer1));
        }
    }`

Comment: `if(!e1.getText().equals("")){}` ?  BTW, don't use e1, e2, n1, n2.  Use width, height etc.

Comment: That statement didn't work the app still crashes on no input. Also thanks about the naming. Your right I should get rid of the bad naming habit

Comment: @jyoon I wish I could downvote comments.  Using try-catch to check user input?  Really????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if there is input in both `EditText`s and only if there is convert it to `Double`:

```
if (e1.getText().length() == 0 || e2.getText().length() == 0) {
    t1.setText("Please enter a number into both the base and height");
} else {
    n1 = Double.parseDouble(e1.getText().toString());
    n2 = Double.parseDouble(e2.getText().toString());
    answer1 = ((n1 * n2) / 2);
    t1.setText(Double.toString(answer1));
}
```

`EditText.getText()` will never return `null` (as per source code) so it's safe to use methods on it (such as `length()`.

Comment: Glad I could help! Good luck and don't forget to check this as correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!e1.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
   // do stuff
}
```